# ¿Como comparo elementos de un String con elementos de Otro para retornar un booleano en JAVA?

Tags: java, lista, poo, arraylist, java-8

Les comento: Tengo un problema a resolver que es para un juego de poker, especificamente tengo un metodo en Java que se llama verificar y recibe 5 cartas como parametros. Las 5 cartas son en String, y la carta se indica con las iniciales tipo "JD" ahi seria J de diamantes, etc.
El problema es que el metodo verifica si en la mano que le toco de 5 cartas hay juego de poker, es decir, de las 5 cartas 4 tienen el mismo numero, o simbolo(J,Q,K,A) y retorna un booleano indicando si tiene poker o no.

Como evaluo eso? no se me ocurre, le di mil vueltas.

meti las 5 cartas en una lista y pienso como evaluar comparandolas pero no se me ocurre como. Si hay alguna idea mejor que una lista la agradeceria.

---

Lo tengo asi:

private ArrayList cartas = new ArrayList();

```
//recibe las 5 cartas de la mano y retorna true si hubo poker
public Boolean verificar(ICarta carta1,ICarta carta2, ICarta carta3, ICarta carta4, ICarta carta5) {
    
    cartas.add(carta1);
    cartas.add(carta2);
    cartas.add(carta3);
    cartas.add(carta4);
    cartas.add(carta5);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Pero parecería que usando Expresiones Lambda y Stream (Java 8+) podrías resolver esto de la forma más sencilla posible.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! estuve pensando eso pero alguna idea que mensaje de exp lambda o stream serviria para eso? mira, te comento, quiero comparar entre cada una de las cartas recibidas como parametros , cuales tienen el mismo numero de al menos 4 de las 5 cartas recibidas. Las cartas son string y se leen como "JD" J de diamantes, "KC" Rey de corazones, y asi. gracias!!!!

Comment: Ponme varios ejemplos de manos de póquer, pa darme cuenta

Comment: Por otra parte, si carta es una clase te recomiendo que separes la numeración y el tipo en propiedades diferentes, ej número que tendría el número de la carta y tipo que tendría si es diamante, corazón etc, actualmente lo tienes junto

Comment: Luciano, las aclaraciones van en la misma pregunta, por favor edítalo ahi

Answer (score 0):

El **algoritmo** es bastante sencillo.

1. Ordenas el arreglo para tener todas tus cartas en orden (da igual si es ascendente o descendente)
2. Filtras todos aquellos que tengan el mismo valor que tu segunda carta (A, 2, ..., Q, K)
3. Si el número de elementos filtrados es diferente a 4, significa que no tienes póker

**¿Por qué se compara con la segunda carta?**

En realidad se podría comparar con la segunda, tercera o cuarta carta, dado que para un póker existen dos escenarios:

1. Al ser ordenadas, las primeras 4 cartas son del mismo número
2. Al ser ordenadas, las últimas 4 cartas son del mismo número

**En código Java.**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Poker of J
        System.out.println(hasPoker("JD", "JT", "JP", "JC", "9D"));
        // Poker of nines
        System.out.println(hasPoker("9D", "9T", "9P", "9C", "4D"));
        // NOT Poker
        System.out.println(hasPoker("9D", "7T", "9P", "4C", "4D"));

    }


    /**
     * This method is used to know if the player's hand is poker
     * @param hand carts in hand
     * @return returns true if the hand is poker, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the number of cards in hand differs from 5 
     */
    private static boolean hasPoker(String... hand) {
        if(hand.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 5 cards, got " + hand.length);
        }
        Arrays.sort(hand);
        // Este substring lo que hace es quitar el palo dejando únicamente el número de la carta (A, 2, ..., 10, ..., K)
        String poker = hand[2].substring(0, hand[2].length() - 1);
        return Arrays.stream(hand).filter(el -> el.startsWith(poker)).count() == 4;
    }

}
```

**Explicación del código**

- Se declara un método que recibe una mano (`private static boolean hasPoker(String... hand)`)

  - Como verás recibe un argumento de "n" variables tipo String (`String...`), por ello mismo debemos de arrojar una excepción si la mano es inválida

```java
if(hand.length != 5) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 5 cards, got " + hand.length);
}
```

- Se ordenan los elementos recibidos con el método [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))
- Se filtran los elementos cuya primera letra sea igual a la primera letra del segundo elemento con ayuda de [`Streams.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)
- Se cuentan el número de elementos que sobraron con [`Streams.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)
- Se devuelve verdadero si el conteo es igual a 4, falso de lo contrario

**Resultados de la ejecución**

```java
true
true
false
```

**EDIT**

Se propone una segunda solución evitando temas más avanzados como los *Streams* o los *varargs*

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Poker of J
        System.out.println(hasPoker2(new String[]{"JD", "JT", "JP", "JC", "9D"}));
        // Poker of nines
        System.out.println(hasPoker2(new String[]{"9D", "9T", "9P", "9C", "4D"}));
        // NOT Poker
        System.out.println(hasPoker2(new String[]{"9D", "7T", "9P", "4C", "4D"}));

    }

    /**
     * This method is used to know if the player's hand is poker
     * @param hand carts in hand
     * @return returns true if the hand is poker, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the number of cards in hand differs from 5
     */
    private static boolean hasPoker2(String[] hand) {
        if(hand.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 5 cards, got " + hand.length);
        }
        Arrays.sort(hand);

        if (hand[0].substring(0, hand[0].length() - 1).equals(hand[3].substring(0, hand[3].length() - 1)))
            return true;
        return hand[1].substring(0, hand[1].length() - 1).equals(hand[4].substring(0, hand[4].length() - 1));
    }
}
```

**Nota:**

Como se puede observar, se evalúan los dos casos mencionados en la respuesta a **¿Por qué se compara con la segunda carta?** en estas líneas

```java
if (hand[0].substring(0, hand[0].length() - 1).equals(hand[3].substring(0, hand[3].length() - 1)))
            return true;
return hand[1].substring(0, hand[1].length() - 1).equals(hand[4].substring(0, hand[4].length() - 1));
```

**EDIT 2**

De igual manera se pueden proponer soluciones que no necesiten ordenamiento como las siguientes:

```java
     // Se necesita hacer el import de java.util.ArrayList
     /**
     * This method is used to know if the player's hand is poker
     * @param hand carts in hand
     * @return returns true if the hand is poker, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the number of cards in hand differs from 5
     */
    private static boolean hasPoker3(String[] hand) {
        if(hand.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 5 cards, got " + hand.length);
        }
        ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<>(5);
        for (String card : hand) {
            if (!set.contains(card.substring(0, card.length() - 1)))
                set.add(card.substring(0, card.length() - 1));
        }
        return set.size() == 2;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to know if the player's hand is poker
     * @param hand carts in hand
     * @return returns true if the hand is poker, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the number of cards in hand differs from 5
     */
    private static boolean hasPoker4(String[] hand) {
        if(hand.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 5 cards, got " + hand.length);
        }
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(5);
        for (String card : hand) {
            set.add(card.substring(0, card.length() - 1));
        }
        return set.size() == 2;
    }
```

Donde se implementa un [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) o tratando de imitar su comportamiento un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), los cuales guardan sin repetición los valores de los números que tienes en tu mano. Si tienes sólo 2 números distintos en tu mano, significa que tienes póker, de lo contrario no.

Comment: Bueno, el comentario es que lamento que el código esté en inglés, pero te recomendaría empezar a emplear el inglés en tus programas, puesto que es el idioma estándar para programar. Espero te ayude esta respuesta

Comment: La respuesta está genial, pero al ser claramente un ejercicio de clase, me parece que usa características muy poco apropiadas. Si lo ves desde el punto de vista de un profesor (o alumno), este ejercicio está pensado para aprender a trabajar con arrays. Si están aprendiendo a manejar arrays, meterse en Streams me parece un poco *excesivo*! Igual que el uso de varargs en el método. Sería más fácil de entender por alguien que está empezando si usase solo características *"básicas"* del lenguaje (arrays y bucles, vaya)

Comment: Realmente me fui por la respuesta de hacerlo con *streams* por los comentarios, pues quien pregunta hace mención sobre cómo se implementaría una solución con ellos, aunque a ver si al rato puedo actualizar la respuesta para incluir la respuesta para principiantes

Comment: Como comentario final, creo que la solución más optimizada es la solución **hasPoker4** dado que es un algoritmo meramente lineal, que no necesita el ordenamiento de las cartas.

Comment: Les agradezco a todos por la ayuda brindada!! graciasss

Comment: @lucianoSantoleri La mejor forma de agradecer es aceptar la respuesta que más te haya servido. Esto ayuda a que otras personas que tengan la misma duda o que vean tu pregunta puedan ver cuál es la respuesta que te ha servido para resolver tu problema. Y si te gusta lo suficiente la respuesta, votar arriba.